# Comic about a man with a self-sustained spaceship moving about as the Galactic Arbitrator in search of God

Tags: story-identification, comics, space

Read this in the nineties. Could have been from earlier. Man with self-sustained spaceship moves about as the Galactic Arbitrator in search of God. Finds him on a pleasure planet held captive by humans. Graphic nudity but good storyline.

Answer (score 5):

Probably [The Vagabond of Limbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vagabond_of_Limbo) (Le Vagabond des Limbes), the fifth volume L'Alchimiste suprême (An Ultimate Alchemist).

Detailed description of the episode can be found [here.](http://theporporbooksblog.blogspot.com/2021/05/an-ultimate-alchemist.html)

> With the aid of Frankchik, Munshine and Musky make their way to 'The Forbidden Perimeter', where, it is rumored, God himself - known as the Ultimate Alchemist - makes his home. And if anyone can bring Chimeer to life, it will be the Ultimate Alchemist........

(saucy content under spoiler)

> [image: Image of "God" on the pleasure planet]

[image: The cover of Dutch translation]